# Remove a specific id from all the collections in single query mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have Reviews collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac47af5e935d927a03518ac"),
    "venue" : ObjectId("5abc9436b7c99332f0a68136"),
    "content" : "gfhfghfghfghf",
}
```

I have Event collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abce7208b9efa5a6b8e739b"),
    "venue" : ObjectId("5abc9436b7c99332f0a68136"),
    "description" : "22222222222222222222222222222222222222",
}
```

I have Venues collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abc9436b7c99332f0a68136"),
    "name" : "ASA College - Manhattan Campus",
    "addedBy" : ObjectId("5abc93a85d3914318cc8d3d7"),
    "__v" : 0,
}
```

How do I remove `Reviews` and `Events` on deleting its corrosponding `Venue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite difficult to create a single query that performs the deletion action for the collection you want to delete and its related collection. But, what you can do is:

1. Remove the venue document using the `_id` value of the `venue` document. You can use `findByIdAndRemove()` which will also give you the deleted `venue` document.
2. Using the `_id` of this `venue` document you can query the `Reviews` collection to delete all the `Reviews` document that has `_id` of `venue` in its `venue` property as a reference.

**sample code**

```
Venue.findByIdAndRemove(idOfVenue, function (err, venueObj) {
    if(err){
      console.log('Error in deleting Venue');
    } else {
      Reviews.remove({venue: venueObj._id}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error in deleting Reviews');
        } else {
          console.log('Record deleted successfully!!');
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

But however you can set up your schema in such a way that when you remove `venue` then `reviews` associated with that `venue` is deleted from the schema level.

```
// Remove Venue
Venue.remove({_id: vanueId}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
       console.log('Error in removing venue');
    }
});

//Remove Reviews related to venue, this code is placed in Venue schema
VenueSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    this.model('Reviews').remove({ venue: this._id }, next);
});
```

Using `pre` on `remove` operation will first remove the record from `Reviews` collection and then remove a record from `Venue` collection. Thus, You have only one query that is to remove the `Venue` record. Removing from `Reviews` is handled at the schema level of `Venue`.

Comment: Thanks Ankit... But can It be possible to delete it single query... I heard about bulk query but don't know how to use it.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary edited my answer. Check now. This should be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB being a NoSQL database doesn't support relations instead alternatively it facilitates defining relational model using embedded documents.

According to above mentioned description,To delete all reviews and events associated to specific venue ,remove operation needs to executed into multiple steps with first step to execute remove operation to remove all reviews and events using filter of venue and then into second step perform operation to remove venue using filter of _id representing venue Id field

Alternatively events and reviews can be defined as an embedded document within venue document as mentioned into below example.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5abc9436b7c99332f0a68136"),
    "name": "ASA College - Manhattan Campus",
    "addedBy": ObjectId("5abc93a85d3914318cc8d3d7"),
    "__v": NumberInt(0),
    "reviews": [{
        "content": "gfhfghfghfghf"
    }],
    "events": [{
        "description": "22222222222222222222222222222222222222"
    }]
}
```

The above document schema will facilitate delete operation of venue and its associated reviews and events into a single operation.