# query to get all _id in array in mongdb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf92"),
    "venue" : ObjectId("5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf8c"),
    "author" : ObjectId("5ac8ba3582c2345af70d4658"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf93"),
    "venue" : ObjectId("5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf8c"),
    "author" : ObjectId("5ac8ba3582c2345af70d4658"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf91"),
    "venue" : ObjectId("5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf8c"),
    "author" : ObjectId("5ac8ba3582c2345af70d4658"),
}
```

how to get all _id in an array having same venue

My output should be like this

```
{array: ['5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf91', '5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf91', '5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf93']}
```

Comment: You want for a specific venue or grouped per venue?

Comment: @Cristy for specific venue

Comment: take a look at this [aggregation: $push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)

Comment: @felix you are awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
db.colelction.aggregate([
  {$match:{"venue" : ObjectId("5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf8c")}},
  {$group:{_id:null, array:{$push:"$_id"}}},
  {$project:{_id:0}}
])
```

And the output is:

```
/* 1 */
{
   "array" : [ 
       ObjectId("5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf92"), 
       ObjectId("5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf93"), 
       ObjectId("5acdb95d5ea63a27c1facf91")
   ]
}
```

Comment: hi is there any play ground for mongodb query?

Comment: @AshishChoudhary what was your question?

Comment: my above commented question is besides of SOF question

Comment: I understand that, what is meant by `playground` ? u mean third party tool besides mongo shell?

Comment: just like jsfiddle

Comment: @AshishChoudhary you can take a look at [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/)! (disclosure: I'm the author )

Comment: @felix awesome share man :) How to test collections with embedded documents there?

Comment: @RahulRaj sure use json mode and define custom json documents, for example [mongoplayground.net/p/7uQ7goYnuQX](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7uQ7goYnuQX)

Comment: @felix please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705054/remove-a-specific-idreferenced-ids-from-all-the-collections-in-single-query-m

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

  // Pipeline
  [
    // Stage 1
    {
      $group: {
         _id:{venue:'$venue'},
         _ids:{$addToSet:'$_id'}
      }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
      $project: {
      _ids:1,
      _id:0
      }
    }

  ]


);
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.